# How to scrape dynamic content displayed in tooltips using scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, tooltip

I'd like to extract the text inside the class "spc spc-nowrap" using scrapy and the container software docker to scrape dynamically loaded content.

```
<div id="tooltipdiv" style="position: absolute; z-index: 100; left: 637.188px; top: 625.609px; display: none;">
  <span class="help">
    <span class="help-box2 y-h wider">
      <span class="wrap-help">
        <span class="spc spc-nowrap" id="tooltiptext">
          text to extract
          <br>
          text to extract
          <strong>text to extract</strong>
          <br>
        </span>
      </span> 
    </span>  
  </span>
</div>
```

Which xpath or css syntax returns these data?

```
response.css("span#tooltiptext.spc.spc-nowrap").extract()
```

yields empty list

Answer (score 0):

This should extract all of the text including the text in the `<strong>` tag.

It will be a list of, for your example the output would be: `["text to extract", "text to extract", "text to extract"]`

```
response.xpath('//span[@id="tooltiptext"]//text()').getall()
```